# Is there any way to make a variable length array global in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, global-variables

I've created a variable length array in one function, however I need to refer to this array in a second function. The problem occurs when I put the declaration above main() seeing as its length hasn't been defined yet, my compiler gets angry.

How does one typically go about this?

**EDIT:**

Here is my code so far.

I need to make the array's **name[] midterm[] and final[]** global. They're all in **student_input()**.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

void student_input();
void student_output();

int i , ns ;

main(){

    int width,height,mult;

    cout << "Enter the number of students:" << endl;
    cin >> ns;

    i = 0 ;
    while( i < ns){
           i = i + 1 ;
           student_input();
           }

    i = 0 ;
    while( i < ns){
           i = i + 1 ;
           student_output();
           }

    system("pause");  
}

void student_input() {
    int si_i,si_midterm,si_final, midterm[ns + 1], final[ns + 1];
    string si_name, name[ns + 1]; 

    cout <<  endl <<  endl << "\t----- Student " << i << " -----" << endl << endl << endl;

    cout << "Enter name for student " << i << ":\t"<< endl;
    cin >> si_name;
    name[i] = si_name ; 

    cout << "Enter midterm score for student " << i << ":\t"<<  endl;

    cin >> si_midterm;
    midterm[i] = si_midterm ;

    cout << "Enter final exam score for student " << i << ":\t"<<  endl ;
    cin >> si_final;
    final[i] = si_final ;

    cout <<  endl <<  endl;

    si_i = 0 ;
    while (si_i < 7){
          si_i = si_i + 1; 
          cout << "Enter lab " << si_i <<" for student " << i << ":\t"<<  endl;
          }

    cout << name[i] <<  endl << midterm[i] <<  endl<<final[i] <<  endl;      
    return;
}

void student_output() {
    cout <<"hello! "<<  endl;
    return;
}
```

Comment: C++ does not have variable length arrays.  Perhaps you are using C?

Comment: C99 does, but I'm tempted to say he's referring to something else. @Anteater: Can we see a code sample please?

Comment: "It's still sloppy since I'm developing it."  First, if you properly format your code, even while developing it, it can help to significantly reduce the time you spend debugging.  Second, it shows a complete lack of respect for the people here that want to help answer your question when you don't take two minutes before posting a question to format your code and make it easy to read.

Comment: Ok I'll clean it up, also I meant sloppy as in many test lines and thing that wouldn't be in the final script.

Comment: This line `name[ns + 1];` is ill-formed in C++. You should be using `std::vector`, VLA's are not in C++. Your compiler is allowing it as an extension.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++ does not support variable length arrays; either you are not using C++ or you are using an implementation-specific language extension.

In C++ you should use `std::vector` for a dynamically sized array.

If you need to access it from multiple functions you can:

- have the functions that need access to the `vector` take a reference to it as an argument, or
- make the `vector` a class member variable and make all the functions that need to access it member functions of the class.

Which one makes more sense depends on what, exactly, you are trying to do.

Comment: @james Can you please explain, "C++ does not support VLA but compiler allows it as an extension" I do understand c++ doesnt support VLA, but the following statemet can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @Als:  What exactly needs further explanation?  C++ doesn't support VLAs.  C99 does.  If the OP is actually using C++ _and_ VLAs then his compiler must support VLAs as a language extension.

Comment: I'm using Bloodshed Dev-c++, for reference.

Comment: @James: If C++ standard doesnt support VLA's then why should a compiler which should be adhering to the standards support such an extension? Should such a discrepancy between standard & the compiler implementation be allowed?

Comment: @Als:  Most (all?) compilers support nonstandard language extensions and few (no?) compilers fully adhere to the language standards.  I don't have a problem with language extensions if they can be turned off or are turned off by default.

Comment: @James: Thanks! Any other such usual/Important extensions that Most(all?) compilers provide as an language extension? Good to know, so can avoid using them.

Comment: @Als: In `gcc/g++`, non-standard extensions can be prevented by compiling with `-ansi -pedantic` option. See: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_28.html

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with `std::vector`? You cannot have a VLA in C++ (g++ provides it as an extension though).

Answer (score 1):

Look into vectors, because although you can in c, in standard c++ theres no way to use variable length arrays.

Also, please look into a new IDE other than bloodshed, such as Code::Blocks, or if necessary, at least a more updated version of Dev c++ than bloodshed.

> 1. Dev-C++ has not been updated since 2005, and is not currently
>      maintained. The software is very buggy.  At the time of my writing
>      there are 340 known bugs that will never be fixed.
> 2. It’s hard to get help, because the programming community have moved on to newer software.
> 3. Dev-C++ lacks features that are present in more modern solutions. Code
>      completion, intellisense, and proper debugging facilities (among
>      others) are not provided.  These tools can greatly improve the
>      workflow and efficiency of an experienced programmer, and may aid the
>      learning of beginners.
> 4. Error messages and the steps required to solve
>      them are poorly documented compared to more modern solutions, and
>      because most programmers have moved on from Dev-C++ it can be
>      difficult (if not impossible) to find anyone who is able to help you. 
>      Some problems may not be able to be solved at all. The compiler
>      included with Dev-C++ is very out-dated, and buggy.  An out-dated
>      compiler can result in buggy and inefficient code, and may be damaging
>      to the learning process for a beginner.
> 5. The provided “devpack” system
>      is no longer supported by modern libraries.  Using external libraries
>      in Dev-C++ can be a confusing and difficult process for beginners who
>      are expecting this simple system to handle it for them.

Note: the beginner things aren't directly pointed at you, this was taken from here: http://clicktobegin.net/programming/why-you-shouldnt-use-dev-c/