# Arrays with a size determined at run time, is this valid in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

So I was talking to my friend, helping her with a piece of code, and I always thought that arrays needed to be compile-time constants, as they are on the stack. But she said that her friend did this using this code:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int value = ' ' ;
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    cout<<"Please enter the total number of employees" <<endl;;
    cin>> value;
    int numbers[value];
    cout<<"Now enter the employees corresponding salaries" <<endl;;
    for (int k = 0; k < value; k++)
    {
        cin >> numbers[k];
    }
}
```

They are using Dev-C++.

Is this code suppose to work? I assume not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to make a variable length array global in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903232/is-there-any-way-to-make-a-variable-length-array-global-in-c)

Comment: Is there any reason that she's initializing `value` to `' '`? The compiler won't care (it'll cast the `' '` char to its ASCII value, `32`), but 32 seems like an odd, random number to initialize an int to.

Comment: They're not coders, just general university students. I couldn't tell you why she choose ' ', \n would of been fine.

Comment: @jValdron: `0` would've been fine `int` isn't `char` ... that's why this looks weird to us.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variable-length arrays are an extension in `gcc` and `g++` ... so this won't work in every compiler.

For more information on `gcc`'s support for variable length arrays, you can see the [documentation here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

Answer (score 4):

I believe that variable length arrays are officially unsupported in C++ but certain compilers and/or language extensions implement them.

If you want a variable length array I recommend using std::vector.
You can view its reference here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

^ is not a standard header. It used to be there in pre-standard times, i.e. before 1998. It's not there in e.g. modern Visual C++.

```
cin>> value;
int numbers[value];
```

Variable Length Arrays, or VLAs, were introduced in C99, a year after C++ was standardized. So they were not part of original standard C++, and happily they were not adopted in C++11 either. Instead of such beast, use e.g. `std::vector` from the `vector` header, or some other standard library container.

g++ supports variable length arrays as a *language extension*. You'd better turn off such extension. E.g.,

```
d:\dev\test> g++ foo.cpp

d:\dev\test> g++ -pedantic -std=c++0x -Wall -O foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
foo.cpp:11: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'numbers'
foo.cpp:7: warning: unused variable 'sum'
foo.cpp:8: warning: unused variable 'count'

d:\dev\test> _
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried compiling it using GCC 4.6, and found that the code you've posted compiled successfully. I also tried running it and found that it worked, but I don't think the code is very good.